# How to create vc++ program which can be install

Tags: visual-c++

Thanks in advance...
     I have a solution in vc++ and it is working fine. I need to create this as a program that can be installed. Also need to create a start menu folder and a desktop icon. What are the steps to create this?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3767/what-is-the-best-choice-for-building-windows-installers

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use an install builder. There's several (free) ones around on the web that you can search for.

Personally, I recommend [InnoSetup by Jordan Russel](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php). It's free, nice, easy to use, and very rich in features : (quoting from website)

> - Support for all versions of Windows in use today: 7, 2008 R2, Vista,
> - XP, 2008, 2003, 2000, Me, 98, 95, and NT 4.0. (No service packs are
>     required.) Extensive support for installation of 64-bit applications
>     on the 64-bit editions of Windows. Both the x64 and Itanium
>     architectures are supported. (On the Itanium architecture, Service
>     Pack 1 or later is required on Windows Server 2003 to install in
>     64-bit mode.)
> - Supports creation of a single EXE to install your
>     program for easy online distribution. Disk spanning is also supported.
> - Standard Windows 2000/XP-style wizard interface.
> - Customizable setup types, e.g. Full, Minimal, Custom.
> - Complete uninstall capabilities.
> - Installation of files: Includes integrated support for "deflate",
>     bzip2, and 7-Zip LZMA/LZMA2 file compression. The installer has the
>     ability to compare file version info, replace in-use files, use shared
>     file counting, register DLL/OCX's and type libraries, and install
>     fonts.
> - Creation of shortcuts anywhere, including in the Start Menu and
>     on the desktop.
> - Creation of registry and .INI entries. Running other
>     programs before, during or after install.
> - Support for multilingual
>     installs, including right-to-left language support.
> - Support for passworded and encrypted installs.
> - Support for digitally signed
>     installs and uninstalls.
> - Silent install and uninstall.
> - Unicode installs. (Windows 2000/XP or later)
> - Integrated preprocessor option
>     for advanced compile-time customization.
> - Integrated Pascal scripting
>     engine option for advanced run-time install and uninstall
>     customization.
> - Full source code is available (Borland Delphi 2.0-5.0
>     and 2009).

Comment: usually I use NSIS for my installers, never tried InnoSetup but often heard about it. Can you compare them?

Comment: @Andy: I have never used NSIS, even though I see plenty of installers built with it, so really can't compare them!

Comment: I have used both of them, personally I find InnoSetup script easier to understand. But I am not expert in both.

Comment: Thanks Cicada It helps me a lot

Answer (score 2):

I would learn Wix if I were you. The current tutorial at http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/ will help you quickly implement the setup for your application. Also, this will be a good investment in knowledge and it will allow you to implement more complex setup applications in the future.